# WPF connect with database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database

I'm new to WPF. I'm now working with a project which is my final year project.
Handling one module which the main point of the module is used to add family member to the system and I do successful added into the system. Now my problem come when I want double confirm whether the data already inserted & I will head to the Server Explorer> Data Connection> house.mdf(Which is my project database)> Tables> family(My table) & double click on it & click on the "Show Table Data" and it still remain empty. That's the stranger part for me.

Later I found out another solution for it is that open with SQL Server 2008 R2 as my database extension is .mdf which compatible with it. As I located the database in the "release" folder inside the bin after I compile and build it and it work for me.

Can all the expert out there tell what the issue that I'm facing?

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36847/Three-Layer-Architecture-in-C-NET)'s a good article on three-layer architecture, and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) is another on MVVM, they may help you with your project. Good luck!

Comment: If I properly understood your problem, the behavior you are experiencing is [this](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2012/05/dealing-with-local-databases-or-why-your-updates-dont-stick.aspx) one.

Comment: Besides that I'm handling my final year project for my academic project. I got one module which is dealing with budgeting for private and family usage such as adding, editing, viewing the daily expense usage. May I ask that got any online references that I can take as an example? Such as source codes, project, and so on in order to have some idead about it :) Any reply is welcome & Thank you.